# Add all Second Items of Each Sublist in List

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

So, I have a list with many sublists that looks something like this:

```
[[(1,2),1],[(5,2),3],[(4,0),2]]
```

And I would like Python to add together the second item in each list, so the `1`, the `3`, and the `2`. I have been trying to find an `itertools` function for it, but I have had no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of `itertools`, just use `sum` with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator-expression):

```
>>> lis = [[(1,2),1],[(5,2),3],[(4,0),2]]
>>> sum(x[1] for x in lis)
6
```

Comment: I am confused. I am not sure if he expects `sum` or just the second items.

Comment: @thefourtheye *Python to **add** together the second item in each list*